# Compare xml node values in xsl and highlight differences

Tags: xslt

I have an xml. I am transforming it using xsl stylesheet and showing in html page using java. My requirement is , I need to compare two node values and if there is a difference, I need to highlight the changed character value. How can this be done ?

XML :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<Message> 
<DiffDetailMessage>
    <TestCaseID>000001</TestCaseID>     
    <res1>VI7002 1D</res1>
    <res2>VI7002 DD </res2>
</DiffDetailMessage>
<DiffDetailMessage>
    <TestCaseID>000002</TestCaseID>
    <res1>BS7002 1D</res1>
    <res2>BS7002 SS  </res2>
</DiffDetailMessage>
</Message>
```

XSL :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/">
<html>
<body>
<h2>Report</h2>  
<xsl:apply-templates/> 
</body>
</html>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Message/DiffDetailMessage">
<table border="2">  
<xsl:apply-templates select="TestCaseID"/>  
<xsl:apply-templates select="res1"/>
<xsl:apply-templates select="res2"/>    
</table>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="TestCaseID">
<tr><td><b>Test CaseID </b></td> 
<td><xsl:value-of select="."/></td></tr>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="res1">
<tr><td><b>Res1</b></td>
<td><xsl:value-of select="."/> </td> </tr>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="res2">
<tr><td><b>Res2</b></td>
<td><xsl:value-of select="."/></td> </tr>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

How can I compare node values res1 with res2 ? In my case, value of "VI70002 ID" should be compared against "VI7002 DD" and since there is a change, I should highlight "D" character in html page using xsl. Can someone help on this regard.

Comment: Are you able to use XSLT2? I'm fairly XSLT2 has capabilities that would make this a lot easier than XSLT1.

Comment: It's a tough problem to do well. Consider buying DeltaXML which is a technology devoted to the task of differencing XML documents.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using only XSLT-1.0, you can use a recursive named template to iterate over the string char-by-char: the following template takes two strings as input and puts a *bold* emphasis on each different char. If the second string is longer than the first one, these trailing chars are highlighted, too.

```
<xsl:template name="cmp">
  <xsl:param name="str1" />
  <xsl:param name="str2" />
  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="substring($str1,1,1) = substring($str2,1,1)">
      <xsl:value-of select="substring($str2,1,1)"/>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:when test="substring($str1,1,1) != substring($str2,1,1)">
      <b><xsl:value-of select="substring($str2,1,1)"/></b>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:when test="$str1 = '' and substring($str2,1,1)">
      <b><xsl:value-of select="substring($str2,1,1)"/></b>
    </xsl:when>
  </xsl:choose>
  <xsl:if test="string-length($str1) > 0 or string-length($str2) > 0">
    <xsl:call-template name="cmp">
      <xsl:with-param name="str1" select="substring($str1,2)" />
      <xsl:with-param name="str2" select="substring($str2,2)" />
    </xsl:call-template>
  </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

Call this template from one of the other templates to get a (partially) highlighted "string", e.g.

```
<xsl:template match="res2">
<tr><td><b>Res2</b></td>
<td>
    <xsl:call-template name="cmp">
        <xsl:with-param name="str1" select="../res1" />
        <xsl:with-param name="str2" select="." />
    </xsl:call-template>
</td> </tr>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: But of course comparing two strings is a small part of the job of comparing two XML documents.